# Add file command in Git Bash

Tags: git, bash, addition

I first navigated to the correct directory in Git Bash (desktop where I had saved my file) and typed in the following after the $:
git add HelloWorld.md

Git Bash's response is
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
I tried moving the file to Documents 
got the same message
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have done

```
git init
```

and you see the `.git` file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all you've done is navigate to the file you wish to upload and typed `git add myfile`, that won't actually work. There's a small process you have to go through to set up a git directory in a given folder.

Step 1: `git init` in the directory you plan on pushing to github.

Step 2: `git add .` to add all files or `git add yourFile` for one file

Step 3: `git commit -m "first commit"` to commit your additions

Step 4: `git remote add origin your_remote_repository_url` to link it

Step 5: `git remote -v` to verify

Step 6: `git push origin master` to upload it to github for good